# Imprimir renglones con bordes abajo teniendo multicell y cell al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy tratando de imprimir un pdf con el detalle de un presupuesto, en el medio implemento el metodo multicell (ya saben para el detalle del articulo que a veces es largo tenga saltos de linea).

Y obtengo esto en la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código del detalle de la tabla es:

```php
foreach($arraydetalle as $detail)
{
    if ($detail['producto']==0){
        $mostrar=$detail['servicio'];
    }else{
        $mostrar=$detail['nombre'];
    }
    $y = $pdf->GetY(); 
    $pdf->Cell(50, 10, $detail['codigo'], 'B', 0, 'L', 1);   

    $pdf->multiCell(80, 10, $mostrar,'B','L',1);    
    $yFin = $pdf->GetY(); 
    $pdf->SetXY(135,$y); 
    $pdf->Cell(15, 10, $detail['preciod'], 'B', 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 10, $detail['cantidadd'], 'B', 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 10, $detail['preciod'] * $detail['cantidadd'], 'B', 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->SetY($yFin);
    $total += $detail['preciod'] * $detail['cantidadd'];
 
}
```

De que manera podría imprimir un renglón ancho y que salga el borde debajo.

Comment: por este motivo prefiero armar todo en una tabla html y pasarla como contenido...

Comment: eso tambien se hace con fpdf?

Comment: bueno en teoria yo migre de fpdf a mpdf... XD